# How to find sender of an attached email with ews

Tags: java, exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi, mail-sender

In EWS, the `EmailMessage` has a sender (`emailMessage.getSender()`) and may has attachments (`emailMessage.getAttachments()`).

These attachments can be `FileAttachment` (for files) or `ItemAttachment` (for attached email).

There is a lot of information on this item attachment such as :

- To : ((ItemAttachment) attachment).getItem().getDisplayTo();
- Subject   : ((ItemAttachment) attachment).getItem().getSubject();
- see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/aa580790(v=exchg.140).aspx

But how to find the sender of this attached  email ?

**Edit :** 
Using EWS Java API 1.1.5 
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ewsjavaapi/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=5754

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the SliverNinja response, I tried to retrieve the item as an email message.
Using EWS with Java, you have to cast the item `ItemAttachment` as `EmailMessage` like this:

```
Item item = ((ItemAttachment) attachment).getItem();
if (item instanceof EmailMessage) {
    String sender = ((EmailMessage)item).getSender().getAddress();
}
```

The item can also be cast as Appointment or Contact or Task or ContactGroup.

**Edit :** 
Another way to get the sender is

```
((EmailMessage) item).getFrom().getAddress();
```

This looks like to do the same

Answer (score 1):

In c# - you could access the [`ItemAttachment.Message`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/aa562997%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx) and then [`Message.Sender`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/aa494306%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx). Once you have the sender, you can retrieve [`Sender.Mailbox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/aa579529%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx) for accessing the [`Mailbox.EmailAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/aa565036%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx). Maybe you can convert this to something similar for java.

```
ItemAttachment itemAttachment = attachment as ItemAttachment;
itemAttachment.Load();
Sender sender = itemAttachment.Message.Sender;
Mailbox mailbox = sender.Mailbox;
string email = mailbox.EmailAddress;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for but unfortunatly, there isn't `Message` on ItemAttachment.